# Can't use first-of-type selector with child selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target the first instance of a `.row` directly in it's `.page-container` parent. I can't get the `:first-of-type` selector to properly target the first instance of `.row`.

```css
.page-container > .row:first-of-type {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="row">Target This Row</div>
  <div class="row">Don't Target</div>
  <div class="row">Don't Target
    <div class="row">Don't Target</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me target only the first instance of `.row` that is a direct descendant of `.page-container`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k54x0czj/

Comment: As @potashin pointed out, your code seems to work just fine. Unless we're misunderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across this issue relatively recently.

The issue is that `:first-of-type` specifically means *first-of-this-type-of-**element*** and it cannot (and does not) apply to classes.

In order to have a selector that applies to classes, we will need either a `:first-of-class` or a `:first-of-query` (which can select *anything* - including classes) - and, so far, neither exist.

Consequently you need something like this:

```
.page-container div:first-of-type.row
```

which means:

> the first `div` nested inside `.page-container` - but *only* if it
>   also happens to have the class `.row`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
.page-container > .row:first-child {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually ignore class or id all together and focus on the tag names, then if it's too broad, I narrow it down by adding class or id to parent.

```css
div > div:first-of-type {
  background: blue;
}
div.page-container > div:first-of-type {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
p:first-of-type {
  color: blue
}
p:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Example #1 in blue background</p>
<p>Example #2 in red border</p>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="row">Target This Row</div>
  <div class="row">Don't Target</div>
  <div class="row">Don't Target
    <div class="row">Don't Target</div>
  </div>
</div>
```